# After migration i got the AbstractModel Not found Error

Tags: magento2

Below is the error which i am getting :

> Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel' not found
>   in  vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractExtensibleModel.php on line
>   16

Can one help me to reduce this error thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

> remove **var/cache** **var/generation** **var/page_cache** folder.

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: no one cmmand work

Comment: givse same error